# How to call a C++ function with reference parameter from c#?

Tags: c#, c++

Given

```cpp
struct Vector3f
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

void getLocalBounds(BoxShape* boxShape, Vector3f& min, Vector3f& max)
{
   min.x = 3;
}
```

Can I call this C++ function from C# and get the value of `min.x` as 3 like this?

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Vector3f
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;
}

[DllImport("a.lib", EntryPoint = "getLocalBounds", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static void getLocalBounds(IntPtr boxShapePtr, ref Vector3f min, ref Vector3f max);

public void Test()
{
   IntPtr boxShapePtr = null; // suppose a valid construction
   Vector3f a, b;
   a.x = 100;
   getLocalBounds(boxShapePtr, ref a, ref b);

   Assert(a.x == 3); // suppose a.x is assigned by c function;
}
```

`Vector3f getBoundMin();` works, but it's passing value on stack rather than reference on stack

Comment: That "C" code is *not* C, it's C++. C doesn't have references.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use P/Invoke for something like this? For small functions it might be easier to just port or rewrite the functions in c#. For a larger API I would use C++/CLI, since it avoids some of the complexity with marshalling calls. While there are certainly use cases for P/Invoke, make sure you are not unnecessarily complicating your program.

Comment: It is working, why complain?  All local variable are one the stack.  You may be seeing the values in the parent stack space and not the child stack space.  So you have to determine where the parent stack space ends and where the child stack begins.  You are also use an optimizer which may be combining the parent and child methods into one method.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, keep in mind that the marshaller will insert some code to between the C# and C++ side. So I would do some profiling before making any assumptions about performance. Just because you write something in C++ does not mean it will be faster.

Comment: `Vector3f getBoundMin();` I don't see that in your code.  "works, but it's passing value on stack rather than reference on stack" how do you know that and why do you care?